# How to iterate over many properties in Twig loop?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem with properties in (probably) Twig. I have controller in Symfony where **getCategories()**, **getWords()**, **getTranslations()** methods (from Doctrine) return the objects (relations). Every property in the controller is an array because I call **findAll()** method (from Doctrine again) which returns the array. Finally I return all the properties from controller to view (Twig file) where I try display the results by Twig for loop.

The problem is the Twig loop only iterates over *flashcards* property (I know why ;)) and I have no idea how to make many-properties iterating. I'd like the loop to iterate over all properties returned by the controller.

In the controller foreach loop I tried update the *flashcards* array with new associative keys such as: *category*, *word* and *translation* so that all the results returned by Doctrine (including relations) are stored in one *flashcards* property but then Symfony throws exceptions.

I wondered if create one array in the controller to which I would push the *flashcards*, *cateogry*, *word* and *translation* arrays and then return this one array to the view but I don't think this is good practice.

Here's the controller method code:

```
public function showAllCards()
{
    $flashcards = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Flashcards::class)
        ->findAll();

     foreach ($flashcards as $flashcard) {
        $category = $flashcard->getCategories()->getName();
        $word = $flashcard->getWords()->getWord();
        $translation = $flashcard->getTranslations()->getWord();
    }

      return $this->render('try_me/index.html.twig', [
        'flashcards' => $flashcards,
        'category' => $category,
        'word' => $word,
        'translation' => $translation
    ]);
}
```

Here's the Twig loop code:

```
{% for flashcard in flashcards %}

  {{ word }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.pronunciation }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.exampleSentence }}
  <br>
  {{ category }}
  <br>
  {{ translation }}
  <br>

{% endfor %}
```

I tried to execute the following controller code...

```
public function showMeAll()
{
    $flashcards = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Flashcards::class)
        ->findAll();

     foreach ($flashcards as $flashcard) {
        $flashcards['categories'] = $flashcard->getCategories()->getName();
        $flashcards['words'] = $flashcard->getWords()->getWord();
        $flashcards['translations'] = $flashcard->getTranslations()->getWord();
    }

      return $this->render('try_me/index.html.twig', [
        'flashcards' => $flashcards,
    ]);
}
```

...with the following Twig loop...

```
{% for flashcard in flashcards %}

  {{ flashcard.words }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.pronunciation }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.exampleSentence }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.categories }}
  <br>
  {{ flashcard.translations }}
  <br>

{% endfor %}
```

...but then Symfony says:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Words could not be converted to string").**

Could you give me some tips how to solve this problem, please? I'd like the Twig loop to iterates over many properties (*flashcard*, *word*, *category*, *translation*). Or write if there's a better solution, please.

Thank you in advance for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your snippets, I'm guessing you want something like the following:

```
{% for flashcard in flashcards %}
    {% for word in flashcard.getWords() %}
        {{ word }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
    {{ flashcard.getPronunciation() }}<br>
    {{ flashcard.getExampleSentence() }}<br>
    {% for category in flashcard.getCategories()() %}
         {{ category.getName() }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
    {% for translation in flashcard.getTranslations() %}
         {{ translation.getWord() }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Have a look at this [section](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) of the documentation. Basically if you had `foo.bar`, `twig` will test if `bar` is a public property of `foo` and if not test if there is a public `getter`, `getBar`, to fetch `bar`.

---

Some sidenotes in both of your loops, the values `category`,  `word` and `translation` will only hold the last value of your `flashcards`, because you are overwriting the value each time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve. But when I change the controller properties (in foreach loop) then Symfony throws exception as above. 
The problem is I have no idea how to display these all properties (from the controller) in one Twig loop. I guess I should modify 
```
{% for flashcard in flashcards %}
```
but I've no idea what should I put instead of *flashcards*

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired output is though. I'm guessing `getCategories`, `getWords()` and `getTranslations()` return more than one object?

Comment: Exactly yes. That's because I call Doctrine **findAll()** method. I want to get all records from database (from *Flashcards* table) but **categories**, **words** and **translations** fields in Doctrine **Flashcard** class (table in database) are related to Doctrine **Categories**, **Words** and **Translations** classes (tables in database). That's why I call these methods inside foreach loop.

Comment: you could just loops those in `twig` as well, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you! First version before update works corectly! I just had to remove this foreach loop in the controller.  

I'd like to ask you about one thing yet if I can. Is writing code such as ```flashcard.getWords().getWord()``` good practice? I mean if lines like that don't break some programming rules? Sorry for being obtrusive but I'd like to be sure that my code is clean and proper :)

Thank you again!